# SQL Query Grouping Two Columns Into One

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Sorry for the vague Title.

I have a SQL Query

```
SELECT SaleDate, Location, SUM(DollarSales)
FROM [TableName]
WHERE (SaleDate= '2012-11-19' OR SaleDate= '2012-11-12')
GROUP BY SaleDate, Location
ORDER BY Location, SaleDate
```

I get the results as follows

```
SaleDate                    Location    (No column name)
2012-11-12 00:00:00.000     002         21500.38
2012-11-19 00:00:00.000     002         24166.81
2012-11-12 00:00:00.000     016         14723.26
2012-11-19 00:00:00.000     016         12801.00
```

I want the results to look like

```
Location    (Sale on 11/12)    (Sale on 11/19)
002         21500.38           24166.81
016         14723.26           12801.00
```

I don't want to use inner selects. Is there any way I can do this.
And this is on one of our legacy systems that uses SQL Server 2000.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the second and third columns fixed? Will they ***always*** be Nov 12th and Nov 19th? *[This is relatively simple.]* Or do you want them to be dynamically named based on the data? And, if so, do you want a new column for each date that appears in your data? *[If you've got this far, it's relatively complicated.]*

Comment: No, its basically yesterday and the day week before yesterday. I will replace it by DATEADD but as of now i was working on the query. So there will be only 2 date columns in the new query which I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT
Location,
SUM(CASE WHEN SaleDate = '2012-11-12' THEN DollarSales ELSE 0 END)'Sale on 11/12'
SUM(CASE WHEN SaleDate = '2012-11-19' THEN DollarSales ELSE 0 END)'Sale on 11/19'
FROM [TableName]
GROUP BY Location
ORDER BY Location
```

This would only work if columns were static, you would have to change this if the dates change.